# How do I specify which python and which modules are being used in my jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, shell, ipython, jupyter-notebook

When I do

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

I get `'/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7'` in my ordinary python shell and `'/usr/bin/python'` in IPython or my jupyter notebook. I would like to force my jupyter notebook to use this same python that the shell is using. I have installed many modules and would like to be able to use the same ones in jupyter than I am using already in the shell. How can I do this?

Comment: The simplest way is to install IPython and Jupyter with the Python you want them to use. You can do this using pip: `path/to/python -m pip install jupyter`.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! If you put it  as an answer, ill accept it

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to install IPython and Jupyter with the Python you want them to use. You can do this using pip:

```
path/to/python -m pip install jupyter
```

You could alternatively set up the IPython kernel to run with your desired Python without reinstalling the notebook. See [the docs on installing kernels](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html). This is more complicated than just installing everything again, though.

Comment: actually now when I did that, and I try and run jupyter notebook, I get a new error:from IPython.paths import get_ipython_dir
ImportError: No module named IPython.paths. I wonder if now its looking in the wrong directory because its using a different python?

Comment: That means that something is importing an older version of IPython than you need. If you have IPython installed through apt or something similar, try uninstalling that.

Comment: hmm well I installed it via brew. I uninstalled both IPython and jupyter and then installed only jupyter via your answer's suggestion, yet I get the same error. Though actually just pip install jupyter (without specifying the python) also gives the same result

Comment: Can you replicate that by doing `import IPython.paths` in an interactive Python shell? If so, see where it's loading IPython from by doing `import IPython; print(IPython)`

Comment: it works successfully and prints <module 'IPython' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.pyc'>

Comment: If that import works, then that copy of IPython that it finds is the newer one. When it fails, it's finding an older one somewhere. Not easy to know where, though. You may need to edit the code where the error is coming from to see what it's importing from where.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using jupyter from a virtualenv.

In my case I had two kernels named *python3*. Doing a `jupyter kernelspec list` it reported **only one kernel** named *python3* that pointed to an incorrect binary. I removed it using `jupyter kernelpec remove python3` and magically appeared the correct one pointing to my activated virtualenv.

If you need to reinstall the kernel then, *from the bin directory* of the virtualenv you can do,

`./python -m pip install ipykernel
sudo ./python -m ipykernel install`